# PyQT4 Howto print textbox content via Pushbutton to console

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have made an Textbox, and want to copy all content from textbox, and paste via pushbutton.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(943, 655)
        self.textEdit = Qsci.QsciScintilla(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 861, 461))
        self.textEdit.setToolTip(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.textEdit.setWhatsThis(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.textEdit.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.textEdit.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Plain)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 570, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.textEdit.selectAll)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "run", None))

from PyQt4 import Qsci

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I basicly wanna have the pushbutton do print "content of textbox via pushbotton to console.

```
like so 

self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "run", None))
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Paste)

def Paste(self):
    print "content"
```

i have tried alot but none work like.

```
def Paste(self):
    x = QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.textEdit.selectAll)
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are your duplicated connect signal in your call back form signal ?

Anyway, The text box in `QsciScintilla`, I read document is using [QString QsciScintilla::text  (       )   const](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a7652636c0e3541514a374b300477dbb6). For output to console, your just call this method;

```
def Paste (self):
    print self.textEdit.text()
```